# CSS on table not loading until I refresh

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a padding of `25%` on the `th` and `td`.
However; the padding does not apply unless I refresh the page with `CTRL + SHIFT + R`. How come?

Example CSS:

```
table.foo {
    border: 0;
    margin: auto;
    color: #545454;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 25%;
}
th:last-of-type, td:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

It's the `padding-right: 25%` that I use for getting some horizontal space between the cells.

Why is this happening? Is padding not the correct way of doing this?

UPDATE: After testing to keep refreshing the page, I noticed that the spacing changes each time..? Like it's setting itself on a spacing from 0 - 25%

Comment: because your browser caches the stylesheet

Comment: And after you refresh the page again? Is this problem consistent?

Comment: inpect page source to see what css is applied to it and tell if that's the correct one ( before reloading)

Comment: @KobyDouek Yes it is. Everytime I visit the page I have to refresh it just for that bit of CSS to load properly. Everything else loads fine

Comment: @billynoah I don't think that's the issue, that was my first guess aswell. But after trying to load the site with Incognito mode it still didn't work

Comment: Does any of the page content change on each refresh?

Comment: @KobyDouek nope, just the table. This is really freaking me out tbh, never have I ever experienced anything like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding percentages "[refer to the width of the containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-right)". As you cannot set the width of a tr, it doesn't work. Even if it seems to work it is not cross-browser solution. I suggest to set the cells padding in px or to use a div inside cells and set padding in percentages to it.

Comment: Yeah that's probably a better idea. I decided to use the `border-spacing` property to solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear is your doubt based on the CTRL+SHIFT+R, or just simply refreshing?

For the latter, I believe to my knowledge, CSS will not produce its changes dynamically. That is, as mentioned in your problem, you will have to refresh the page every time you make a change in your CSS coding.

Hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: That's not my question. I'm well aware of that I have to refresh the page every time I make a change.. But this bit of code only applies if I fully refresh the page.

Comment: Oh I see so by using the complete refresh only it changes your CSS coding. Sorry for the incorrect answer, I'll look into this since it is new to me too.